# while trying to execute r package using java getting Exited with error code 2

Tags: java, runtime

A small issue while trying to execute `R` package using Java.

```
Runtime run = Runtime.getRuntime(); 
Process pr = null;
String line = null;
BufferedReader input = null;

try {
    pr = run.exec("cmd /c R");
    input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(pr.getInputStream()));

    while((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
      System.out.println(line); 
    }

    int exitVal = pr.waitFor();
    System.out.println("Exited with error code " + exitVal);
} catch (Exception e) {         
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I'm getting `Exited with error code 2`. Could any one help me?

Answer (score 0):

On Windows exit code 2 generally means "file not found". Check in which folder are you are running the "cmd /c R". You can test this by creating a new file and then search your computer where it was created, or by executing the dir.exe command and then checking the result.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you specify the full path of the package R including extension. This is because when run from cmd , it assumes that the file is in the current working directory however, when run from java, the path has to be specified

Your code should look something like this:

```
 pr = run.exec("cmd /c C:/test/R.exe");
```

Note: it doesn't have to be a .exe file I just put it as an example. for other files just change exe to the file's extension.

Hope this helped.